# How do i get an executable from the SDL 2.0 test examples code

Tags: sdl, exe

I just download SDL 2.0. It works perfectly with visual studio 2012 experss. How do I run the examples in the test folder? I tried importing all the files but the most I have been able to do is compile the files into *.obj files with names corresponding to their c class name. How do I actually make executables from these examples?